# How to add-apt-repository ppa on Mac

Tags: linux, bash, macos, zsh, iterm2

I need to add a ppa but I'm on a mac, how can I `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:author-name/example.js` but on Mac?.

I'm using iterm and zsh in case that is relevant.

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 5):

`apt` is a Debian tool. It installs packages on Debian and Ubuntu. You won't have much use for a `ppa` on Mac.

On Mac OS X, packages are installed with Homebrew (`brew`) or Macports (`port`). Homebrew is generally the recommended tool nowadays.

See installation instructions at http://brew.sh.